# Systemverilog size attributes

Tags: system-verilog

Suppose we have a 2d Systemverilog array declared as:

```
logic x [0:3][7:0] ;
```

1. How can we use an attribute to get the width of the first dimension ?
2. How can we use an attribute to get the width of the second dimension ?
3. Is there an attribute equivalent to VHDL's "range" attribute ? I.E: one that'll return not the size but the actual range ( 0 to 3 ) or ( 7 down to 0 ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.7 *Array query functions*, describes all that you need:

```
module tb;

logic x [0:3][7:0] ;

initial begin
    for (int i=1; i<=$dimensions(x); i++) begin
        $display;
        $display($size (x, i));
        $display($left (x, i));
        $display($right(x, i));
        $display($low  (x, i));
        $display($high (x, i));
        $display;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
      4
      0
      3
      0
      3


      8
      7
      0
      0
      7
```

See also [System Tasks And Functions Part-II](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/system_task_function2.html)

Comment: Is IEEE Std 1800-2017 freely available ?
If yes, where can it be download ?

Comment: @shaiko Click on the [IEEE Get Program](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7932212)